# Gradle Kotlin DSL: Define Kotlin version in unique place

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

For describing Gradle build scripts, we can use Kotlin via `build.gradle.kts` files. It's a common problem to globally define **the** Kotlin version to be used, both in the `dependencies` and also in the build `plugin` section (It's rather uncommon to have different versions in use for the given case).

Consider the following code (Gradle 4.3.1):

```
plugins {
    var pluginVersion = "1.2.30"
    kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)
    // more
}

var dependencyVersion = "1.2.30"
dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib", kotlinVersion))
    compile(kotlin("reflect", kotlinVersion))
    testCompile(kotlin("test", kotlinVersion))
    // more
}
```

As you can see, the kotlin `version` (1.2.30 in this case) is defined *twice*: `dependencyVersion` and `pluginVersion`, which very often **does not differ**. Due to DSL restrictions, it is impossible to access the `pluginVersion` from outside the `plugins` block or access the `dependencyVersion` from within the `plugins` block.

How can the version string, `"1.2.30"` be extracted to a single place?

Comment: kotlin version constant is part of gradle-kotlin-DSL. Usage samples: `implementation(embeddedKotlin("stdlib-jdk7"))`
or
`classpath(embeddedKotlin("gradle-plugin"))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In later versions of Gradle you no longer need to specify the version of your `kotlin(stdlib|reflect|test)` dependencies, the Kotlin plugin will automatically configure them for you.

As for extracting the dependency to a single place, there are two main patterns:

- define the constants you want to share in an object within `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/` and use that object in your build script, code from `buildSrc` is available to the whole script including the `plugins` block
- use a system property, you can define a system property in `gradle.properties` by prefixing its name with `systemProp.` and you can access system properties via `System.getProperties()`, for example:

  ```
  // build.gradle.kts
  plugins {
    val kotlinVersion by System.getProperties()
    println("Kotlin version is $kotlinVersion")
  }

  // gradle.properties
  systemProp.kotlinVersion=1.2.20
  ```

Comment: When defining constants in `buildSrc`, can I also use them in the build.gradle.kts of `buildSrc` itself?

Comment: Note: kotlin version constant is part of gradle-kotlin-DSL. Usage samples: `implementation(embeddedKotlin("stdlib-jdk7"))`
or
`classpath(embeddedKotlin("gradle-plugin"))`

Comment: buildSrc is really a good place and Gradle support such way officially.

Answer (score 32):

What I just stumbled upon was using Kotlin classes ins my `build.gradle.kts`.

I had to:

- create a module called `buildSrc` with `src/main/kotlin` and a `build.gradle.kts` in its root.
- (obsolete) `include("buildSrc")` in `settings.gradle.kts`

The `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` is very minimal:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

In `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` I've added a `Config.kt`

```
const val GROUP_ID = "my-company"
const val VERSION = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

const val POM_NAME = "my-library-name"
const val POM_DESCRIPTION = "A library doing stuff."
const val POM_URL = "https://github.com/${GROUP_ID}/${POM_NAME}/"
const val POM_SCM_URL = POM_URL
const val POM_SCM_CONNECTION = "scm:git:git://github.com/${GROUP_ID}/${POM_NAME}.git"
const val POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION = "scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/${GROUP_ID}/${POM_NAME}.git"
const val POM_LICENCE_NAME = "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
const val POM_LICENCE_URL = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
const val POM_LICENCE_DIST = "repo"
const val POM_DEVELOPER_ID = "me"
const val POM_DEVELOPER_NAME = "meeee"
const val POM_DEVELOPER_EMAIL = "me@foo.com"
```

And a `Dependencies.kt`

```
@file:Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")

object Jvm {
    const val version = "1.8"
}

object Kotlin {
    const val version = "1.3.50"
    const val stdlibJdk8 = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$version"
    const val jvmId = "jvm"
    const val kaptId = "kapt"
}

object MavenPublish {
    const val id = "maven-publish"
}

object Arrow {
    const val version = "0.10.1"
    const val core = "io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:$version"
    const val syntax = "io.arrow-kt:arrow-syntax:$version"
    const val optics = "io.arrow-kt:arrow-optics:$version"
    const val fx = "io.arrow-kt:arrow-fx:$version"
    const val meta = "io.arrow-kt:arrow-meta:$version"
}

object Versions {
    const val version = "0.27.0"
    const val versions = "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:$version"
    const val id = "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
}
```

So I could use it in my root `build.gradle.kts` like

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin(Kotlin.jvmId) version Kotlin.version
    kotlin(Kotlin.kaptId) version Kotlin.version
    id(Versions.id) version Versions.version
    id(MavenPublish.id)
}

group = GROUP_ID
version = VERSION

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Kotlin.stdlibJdk8)
    implementation(Arrow.core)
    implementation(Arrow.syntax)
    kapt(Arrow.meta)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = Jvm.version
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
            pom {
                name.set(POM_NAME)
                description.set(POM_DESCRIPTION)
                url.set(POM_URL)
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set(POM_LICENCE_NAME)
                        url.set(POM_LICENCE_URL)
                        distribution.set(POM_LICENCE_DIST)
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id.set(POM_DEVELOPER_ID)
                        name.set(POM_DEVELOPER_NAME)
                        email.set(POM_DEVELOPER_EMAIL)
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection.set(POM_SCM_CONNECTION)
                    developerConnection.set(POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION)
                    url.set(POM_SCM_URL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite happy with this, but when it comes down to automatically increment the `version` I may fall back to maintain it in the `gradle.properties`.

---

**Edit:**
It is no longer necessary (and allowed) to add `buildSrc` to the `settings.gradle.kts`, instead it will automatically get picked up if present.

Comment: `'buildSrc' cannot be used as a project name as it is a reserved name` in `settings.gradle`

Comment: Yes, this is true for recent versions. BuildSrc also gets automatically picked up if present.

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks! I have only one comment about it, I had exactly the same setup but what your answer made me realize is that I shouldn't import the variable from the dependencies file but use the full import instead i.e, if my dependencies are defined in a file called `Plugins.kt` inside `buildSrc`:

**Don't do** (my mistake): `plugins { id(Kotlin) version KotlinVersion }`

Instead, just **do** : `plugins { id(Plugins.Kotlin) version Plugins.KotlinVersion }`

Comment: I was migrating from Groovy to Kotlin and suddenly my gradle.properties variables are not available anymore. Is there any change required?

Answer (score 8):

You can extract the version from the plugin class:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.0"
}

val kotlinVersion = plugins.getPlugin(KotlinPluginWrapper::class.java).kotlinPluginVersion
```

Comment: You can get the version from KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION

Answer (score 3):

Once you've defined a version for the Kotlin plugin all other Kotlin libraries will use the same version, and do not need a specific version set.

So the *only* place you need to set the version is when defining the classpath for the plugin, e.g.:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")
    }
}
```

If you then need the version for some other purpose (such as in a `resolutionStrategy` or just for information) you can get it from `org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION`

For example:

```
println("Kotlin version used is ${org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION}")
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround available, which searches the version defined for the **kotlin plugin** and assignes this one to the outer variable. The following demonstrates this:

```
val kotlinVersion: String? by extra {
    buildscript.configurations["classpath"]
            .resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
            .find { it.moduleName == "kotlin-gradle-plugin" }?.moduleVersion
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version("1.2.30")
    //more
}
```

The variable `kotlinVersion` can then be used in the `dependencies` without further trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for @s1m0nw1 comment (too long for comment):
No you can't use buildSrc/src stuff in buildSrc/build.gradle. I had exactly this problem as I wrote android-based plugin and I need android gradle plugin dependency in buildsSrc but I also declare this dependency in project. So I had two different places and two versions to maintain.

I resolved this by creating gradle.properties file in buildSrc directory.
In it I've created prop `androidGradlePluginVersion=3.6.0-rc02`

buildSrc/build.gradle:

```
val androidGradlePluginVersion: String by project
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$androidGradlePluginVersion")
```

buildSrc/src/.../Versions.kt:

```
var ANDROID_PLUGIN = loadAndroidGradlePluginVersion()
```

Util for props:

```
val GRADLE_PROPERTIES = "buildSrc/gradle.properties"
val ANDROID_PLUGIN_VERSION_PROP = "androidGradlePluginVersion"

fun loadAndroidGradlePluginVersion(): String {
    Properties().apply { load(FileInputStream(GRADLE_PROPERTIES)) }.let {
        return it.getProperty(ANDROID_PLUGIN_VERSION_PROP)
    }

    error("Provide $ANDROID_PLUGIN_VERSION_PROP in $GRADLE_PROPERTIES")
}
```

Comment: Doing this, I still had to duplicate the property definitions in both buildSrc/gradle.properties and rootProject/gradle.properties. Otherwise, when trying to use the property, such as in buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt, it doesn't find the property. For some reason, it tries to search for the property in the rootProject's buildSrc, skipping the buildSrc's. I've tried for hours to find a solution yet to no avail.

Comment: Okay, so I was eventually able to get around the issue by using this `val gradlePropertiesFile: File = File("${System.getProperty("user.dir")}${if (project.name == "buildSrc") "" else "/buildSrc"}/$GRADLE_PROPERTIES")` as the file from which to load the input stream. (using Kotlin DSL)

Comment: I guess it make sense as it is resolved in runtime instead of compile time.
My bad, I forgot to add my consts:
`GRADLE_PROPERTIES = "buildSrc/gradle.properties"
ANDROID_PLUGIN_VERSION_PROP = "androidGradlePluginVersion"`

Answer (score 2):

Easy and fast workaroud:

In **buildscript** section set value as **system property**:

```
buildscript {   
   val version = "X.X.X"
   System.setProperty("version", version)
}
```

In **plugins** section get this property:

```
plugins {
    val version = System.getProperty("version")
}
```