# How to define the Kotlin version for both buildSrc and an application module?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, multi-module, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using a `buildSrc` module in a multi-module Kotlin project to [manage dependency definitions and versions](https://handstandsam.com/2018/02/11/kotlin-buildsrc-for-better-gradle-dependency-management/). The module makes use of [kotlin-dsl](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) as shown in the *build.gradle.kts*:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

Alternative declaration:

```
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "0.16.2"
}
```

I would like to use the same Kotlin version for compiling the `buildSrc` module as well as within the application module/s. My first attempt was to simply add the JVM artifact:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.31"
}
```

This however leads to a build error which is discussed [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/520):

> Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.2.31']
>   Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version

What is a convenient way to only **define once** the Kotlin version used throughout the project?

## Related

- [Gradle Kotlin DSL: Define Kotlin version in unique place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588311/gradle-kotlin-dsl-define-kotlin-version-in-unique-place)
- [Kotlin versions and the Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/doc/getting-started/Kotlin-Versions.md)
- [Sample project: Multi-kotlin-project-with-buildSrc](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples/multi-kotlin-project-with-buildSrc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each Gradle release is meant to be used with a specific version of the
>   `kotlin-dsl` plugin and compatibility between arbitrary Gradle releases
>   and `kotlin-dsl` plugin versions is not guaranteed.
>
> Using an unexpected version of the `kotlin-dsl` plugin in a build can
>   cause hard to diagnose problems.
>
> Starting with Gradle 5.4, a warning is emitted whenever an unexpected
>   version of the `kotlin-dsl` plugin is detected.

[Paul Merlin @eskatos, 25.04.2019](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1269#issuecomment-486560819)

Therefore, I **removed** the `version`:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, BUT it also forces my application to use that version which is plain ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I'm aware of is putting it into gradle.properties (or any other config) and reading it in settings.gradle.kts `pluginManagement`. Like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id.startsWith("org.jetbrains.kotlin")) {
                useVersion(gradle.rootProject.extra["kotlin.version"] as String)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An error speaks for itself: you can't specify version of plugin in `plugins` folder if you already specified it in `buildscript` block.

You can put `kotlinVersion` into gradle.properties and symlink `buildSrc/gradle.propeties` to `./gradle.properties`