# How to parametrize Kotlin version in the plugins block of a build.gradle.kts script?

Tags: variables, kotlin, scope, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In the script below:

```
val kotlinVersion by extra ("1.3.61")

println("Version "+kotlinVersion)

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
}
```

The variable `kotlinVersion` is correctly printed. Nevertheless it is not recognized in the `plugins` block and the following error is risen:

```
e: /home/achadde/sources/kotlin/minichain/build.gradle.kts:6:27: Unresolved reference: kotlinVersion
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can find mine and more fixes in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953952/8536903

Comment: You can find mine and more fixes in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953952/8536903

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Short answer:

There is currenlty no way of accessing anything of the outer scope from inside the lambda passed to `plugins`.

### Long answer:

In case you use IntelliJ it will show you a bit more information:

> 'val kotlinVersion: String' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary.

The outer scope (`this@Build_gradle`) where you define `kotlinVersion` is not avaiable in the `this@plugins` scope so you have to define `kotlinVersion` inside the plugins lambda.

Since the `extra` delegate isn't available there either you can't use it:

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
    // ...
}
```

---

Unfortunately using a label does not work:

```
val kotlinVersion by extra ("1.3.61")

plugins {
    // ... Unresolved reference: kotlinVersion 
    kotlin("jvm") version this@Build_gradle.kotlinVersion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, the `plugins` block can't read the outer scope, so what I did was added the following entry to my `settings.gradle.kts` instead:

```
pluginManagement.resolutionStrategy.eachPlugin {
    if (requested.id.id.startsWith("org.jetbrains.kotlin.")) {
        useVersion("1.4.10")
    }
}
```

With my `build.gradle.kts` now as follows:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

println(kotlin.coreLibrariesVersion)
```

Note how the version can now be omitted. The following print statement will print out the version we specified in our `settings.gradle.kts`, if we ever want to access our Kotlin version further down in our build script.

Comment: But doesn't this feel like too much work just to refer to a version number?